# JAR File is working in Eclipse but not in CMD ( java.lang.RuntimeException: Environment (windows) with architecture (x86) is not supported)

Tags: java, eclipse, x86, x86-64, speech-recognition

Im trying to create a Voice assitant using Java. Im using the Picovoice API. Java Eclipse runs my code perfectly without any Issues, but when I export the project as Runnable JAR and run it through my cmd ("java -jar WakeWord.jar") Im getting this Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at ai.picovoice.porcupine.Porcupine$Builder.build(Porcupine.java:204)
    at de.VoiceRecognition.ball.WakeWordDetection.main(WakeWordDetection.java:73)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Environment (windows) with architecture (x86) is not supported by Porcupine.
    at ai.picovoice.porcupine.Utils.getArchitecture(Utils.java:196)
    at ai.picovoice.porcupine.Utils.<clinit>(Utils.java:41)
    ... 2 more
```

Im confused because it works in the Eclipse IDE but not on my Desktop through CMD Prompt on Windowsx86(AMD64).

Comment: You probably didn't make the dependencies available which ARE in your IDE. There might even be native dependencies missing

Comment: From the message, I'd say you need to use a 64-bit version of Java.

Comment: Actually what Olivier said looks good. You might be using a different runtime at the command line than the IDE uses.

Comment: Thank youu g00se and Oliver that solved my Problem. I've reinstalled JRE for 64-bits now its working. Have a great Day